# Print media queries and cm

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Why don't print media queries with cm measurements work consistently in every browser. Let's say we want to have two columns that break to one column if the browser width is smaller than 500px (screen) or the page is smaller than 190mm (print, A4 is 210mm).

The HTML is pretty straight forward:

```
<div class="grid-item one-half">
  First column
</div>
<div class="grid-item one-half">
  Second column
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Full width */
.one-half {
  width: 100%;
}

/* A4 is 210mm */
@media screen and (min-width: 500px), print and (min-width: 190mm) {
  .one-half {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}
```

This code works just fine in almost every browser (IE9+) if you resize your browser window. But as soon as I try to print it (CMD+p), I get really different results and I can't figure out why:

**Chrome (43, OSX):** Only shows one column, although I used A4 paper settings (which is 210mm). Only if I change the 190mm to 143mm or less, it shows two columns.

**Safari (8.0.7):** Shows two columns (as expected), but even if I change the 190mm to 300mm (which is far larger than my A4 paper), it keeps showing two columns (up to around 340mm).

**Firefox (36, OSX):** Only browser of all three that works as expected.

To me it seems as if both Chrome and Safari do some kind of scaling, if you try to print a page, so a A4 paper is not 210mm. Is there any way to prevent this, so that the media queries fire correctly?

Although this might not be 100% reliable (`<iframe>`), I put the code in a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/a1ye6tco/embedded/result/). But you can still see the different results for every browser.